# Reformat vertical data to horizontal (side-by-side)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet containing groups of data in a vertical format, e.g. here are three "groups", each with five rows:-

[image]

I would like to reformat the spreadsheet so the values are all side-by-side, like this:

[image]

Is this possible? The real data will contain dozens of groups each containing hundreds of rows, so a manual copy/paste isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each new column in your reformatted table has a certain **offset** to the row number in your original table. You can use the [`OFFSET` function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592?CorrelationId=0433ed8b-84fe-4ed2-9ffe-57e9157fb720&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) of refer to the right cell. With n elements in each target column, each element in your target array on row r and column c refers to the second column and the original table and row number c*n+r.

In your example putting the following formula in B1 and copy-paste it to D5 will do the trick (assuming worksheet names `Original` and `Target`:

```
=OFFSET(Original!$B$1;(ROW(Target!B1)-1)+5*(COLUMN(Target!B1)-2);0)
```

- The `5*` comes from the numer of rows in the target array.
- The `-1` comes from the top-row number of the target array.
- The `-2` is because the target cells are filled from the second column of the target array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cells
Copy
Paste special - here select transpose
```

That's it !

If somehow you cant find paste special it's under the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow below Paste (for office 2007+).